# Is it possible to limit data traffic in kernel USB drivers?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, usb, driver

I am working with a device based on Linux version 2.6.32
This device includes a lte module communicating with device processor via USB.

I am running heavy tcp/udp bi-directional iperf traffic between a remote device in lte network and a PC connected to my device via Ethernet or USB.

The CPU of the device reaches 100%. irq + sirq reach more than 90%.
Because the device is busy with data all the time, there is almost no chance for any of the running tasks to get CPU time.

After some time, between a couple of minutes and several hours, iperf get stuck and the traffic is stopped.
The problem mainly happens when the PC is connected to the device via USB rather than Ethernet. 
And also when using TCP traffic rather than UDP.

I tried several things to limit the traffic or improve behavior including:

- tc (traffic control application)
- set CONFIG_MUSB_PIO_ONLY in kernel
- ethtool, but it is not supported by the hardware

None of them gave significant results.

My current investigation is to make changes in the code of the kernel USB drivers in order to limit the traffic and free resources.
The approach would be to discard packets when a given criteria happens: i.e. CPU or number of interrupts reaches a given threshold.

The changes would be done either in the standard USB driver used

- for communication with lte module in kernel/drivers/usb/host
- for communication with PC in kernel/drivers/net/usb

Does this option seem feasible? I have very few knowledge in kernel USB drivers and I would appreciate any help or recommendation how to proceed.

Comment: It would help if you mentioned some hard facts, such as the type of CPU on your device, the type of communication module and what kind of data rate is it that causes these problems. Incidentally in the not too distant past desktop CPUs could get bogged down with interrupts from low-end NICs that did not have proper receive buffers. You may be able to enable some sort of buffering on your module to reduce this kind of load...

Comment: The processor is TI ARM  AM3517. Lte modules are either Sierra or Sequans. The actual throughput is about 60 Mbps DL and 20 Mbps UL, but the CPU reaches 100% already at about 50 Mbps DL/15 Mbps UL, and iperf stuck with even less than this.

Comment: What kind of packet rate are we talking about here? And more importantly, what is the situation you are trying to defend against? Any server can be overloaded under the right circumstances...

Comment: I want to limit throughput to x Mbps in Down-link and y Mbps in Up-link in the device itself, even though client and/or server (UDP/TCP) are pushing more data. I want to avoid 1) CPU 100% 2) iperf stuck.

Comment: Keep in mind that while the CPU situation is probably sort-of fixable, you cannot in general limit the data rate of incoming data - not unless you have access to other end of the connection. That is why DDoS attacks are so hard to defend against. Perhaps you could just force the wireless link to a lower connection speed?